# Heroku dyno and writing to files

Tags: python, json, heroku, bots, discord.py

I'm running a discord bot with discord.py that reads/writes from/to a json file. Locally, this all works fine, but on Heroku, it seems to use a temp file that it reads/writes to so things work within the bot session, but if I restart the bot at all either by pushing changes or just turning the dyno off and back on, the json is reset to it's original state (and when I cat it even after making changes, it still shows the original state even if the bot functions as though it were edited). How can I make it permanently change the .json?

Comment: Use a database.  Heroku has an 'ephemeral' file system that resets itself upon any deploys or restarts.  If you need to persist data, you should store it to a database.

Comment: Should I use a database from their addons, or would an SQLite database work? @Alexander

Comment: With heroku, you can't use their file system for permanent storage.  You need to use an additional service. Google "heroku file storage options" for more info.  They have a free service tier level for Postgres (Hobby Dev). https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql